# Populating a Partial View with post data

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

**Main objective:**

Be able to click on a day from the calendar plugin then have a popup of a bootsrap modal with events that are listed for that day.

**Whats going on:**

I'm using a javascript plugin fullcalender. This plugin has a `dayClick` event which I am using. Once clicked I have ajax code to pass values to the post as shown:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
@Html.Partial("Modal",null)
    ...  
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            height: 170,
            selectable: true,
            editable: true,
            defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                $.ajax(
                {                        
                    url: '@Url.Action("Index","Home")',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ date: date }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    cache: false
                })
              $("#myModal").modal();                
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

from here it goes to the controller then forces related data to a partial view. Which by debugging I believe is doing it properly.

```
[HttpPost]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public ActionResult Index(string date)
{
    if (date != null)
    {
       string[] dateSplit = date.Split(new char[] { 'T' });
       DateTime objDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateSplit[0]);
       var content = db.Calendars.Where(x => x.startDate == objDate).ToList();
       return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Modal.cshtml", content);
    }
    else
       return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Modal.cshtml", null);
}
```

**The problem:**

Doesn't seem like data is being passed into the partial view, just the original null value. Thought passing data through the post of the index would populate the partial view.

Or could it be the javascript call $("#myModal").modal(); being called before data can populate? I've done some testing of throwing the if(Model != null) around all of the coding in the partial view and an else statement that would display a

tag with elements in it. It always displays the

tag.

**Here is my View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<webby.Models.Calendar>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="padding:20.5% 15%;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Events on @ViewBag.Date</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table>
                @if(Model != null)
                { 
                    @foreach(var item in Model)
                    { 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.events)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.type)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.content)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                  }
               </table>
             </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. You're making an ajax call, but not using the returned result - how would it appear on your page? 2. If `date` is null - you should detect why? What route leads to this action? 3. `$("#myModal").modal();` should be called inside of success callback of ajax request.

Comment: I believe Ilya is correct.  To put it another way, your ajax call is calling a controller action which renders the partial view, returns the partial view, but there's no JS to catch the returned result.  I think you need a success callback option that takes the returned data and populates a container on your page with the returned partial view THEN calls the modal.

Comment: As others have pointed out you need a success handler for your ajax call. You also need to decide how you want your format your response. By using a partial view you are returning an html response. But your ResponseFormat and ajax request are specifying JSON. If you intend to handle json -- drop the partial view and build the html inside your javascript success handler. Otherwise adjust your request and drop the ResponseFormat attribute.

Answer (score 0):

your call to the modal

```
$("#myModal").modal();
```

needs to be done inside a .success function not in the dayClick function.  And you need to pass it the result data of your ajax call.